# GAE: Making many queries into one

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a productpart database containing a string property named 'type'. 
What I'm trying to do is to get all products by a given type (sometimes more then one type).

I've tried to use GAE filter method but can't get it to work properly.

The only solution I've got working is to make a new db.GqlQuery for each type.

The reason I need to fetch each by type is to display them in different 's on the client side?

Is there a way to use just one query for this?

Currently it looks like this :

```
    productPartsEntries = {
                             'color' :  db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM ProductParts WHERE type = :type", type = 'color'),
                             'style' :  db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM ProductParts WHERE type = :type", type = 'style'),
                             'size' :  db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM ProductParts WHERE type = :type", type = 'size')
// add more....
}
```

..fredrik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the IN operator. It would create the three different queries and group the results together for you under the scenes. See the [docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference.html):

> GQL does not have an OR operator.
>   However, it does have an IN operator,
>   which provides a limited form of OR.
>
> The IN operator compares value of a
>   property to each item in a list. The
>   IN operator is equivalent to many =
>   queries, one for each value, that are
>   ORed together. An entity whose value
>   for the given property equals any of
>   the values in the list can be returned
>   for the query.
>
> **Note**: The IN and != operators use multiple queries behind the scenes.
>   For example, the IN operator executes
>   a separate underlying datastore query
>   for every item in the list. The
>   entities returned are a result of the
>   cross-product of all the underlying
>   datastore queries and are
>   de-duplicated. A maximum of 30
>   datastore queries are allowed for any
>   single GQL query.

Comment: Wouldn't ProductParts.gql("WHERE type = :type", type = "color") be the same as using an entire query?

Comment: Yes, that would create the gql query for you, but you can also do `p =  ProductParts.gql("WHERE type IN :types", types=["color", "style", "size"])`